# Same Url but different controller after logged in to the application

Tags: url, authentication, laravel-5, redirect

I want to make simple application using laravel5.2 in which there will come sign in form on base url when i log in to the application there need to give a different view  i.e. Client dashboard at same url. How can i do that Please help me. Thanks In Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple. You have to just make a function in  WelcomeController or in other controller. And do check if user is already login or not and redirect to proper view page accordingly.
For example : 
In your routes.php file write route like this

```
$router->get('/',array(
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'WelcomeController@welcome'
));
```

And in your controller ,in case of this example : WelcomeController make a function named welcome and do some auth check like this

```
public function welcome()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        //get some data for user dashboard
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    return view('login');
}
```

PS: for good practice, use dependency injection. In this case inject Guard
class instead of using Auth facade.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this for root `/` URL:

```php
Route::get('/', function(){
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return View::make('login'); // login view if not authenticated
        // or call controller for login
    }
    else{
        return View::make('dashboard'); // dashboard view if authenticated
        // or call controller for dashboard
    }
});
```